# have any way to unset the value of $_POST and $_GET

Tags: php, post, get

I am trying to build a CSRF function that will work for every request. I just generate the token and verified.

now I want to unset the value of $_POST and $_GET if verification failed so that in my next input validation code isset($_POST["name"]) return false.

I can do if(valided_token) checking in every request but its not my purpose.

have any Idea

Comment: yes. may be that will be fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign to the variables.

```
$_POST = array();
$_GET = array();
$_REQUEST = array();
```

Answer (score 2):

keep it as array, no need for **unset** because you already set it to an empty array.

```
$_POST = array();
$_GET = array();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following to unset $_POST["name"]

```
unset($_POST["name"])
```

If you try to reset the whole array take the solution mentioned by Barmar